# нету метода Label в qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, label

привет у меня проблема когда я хочу спользовать метод label в классе то его нету но в файле .ui я его добавлял я пытался очищать проект и пересобирать не получилось
и когда я хочу получить доступ к методу label у меня его нету
вот еще

```
Image = new ImagesViewer(this);
Image->(здесь должен быть метод label но его нету а в .ui есть виджет label)
```

файл mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_actionAdd_triggered()
{
   mFileName = "";
   ui->textEdit->setPlainText("the file was created you can write");
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
   QString oFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open a file");

   if(!oFile.isEmpty())
     {
       QFile oFile2(oFile);
       if(oFile2.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
         {
           mFileName = oFile;
           QTextStream in(&oFile2);
           QString text = in.readAll();
           oFile2.close();

           ui->textEdit->setPlainText(text);
         }
     }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
   QFile sFile(mFileName);
   if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
     {
       QTextStream out(&sFile);

       out<< ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

       sFile.flush();
       sFile.close();
     }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionSave_As_triggered()
{
   QString sFile = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Save a file");

   if(!sFile.isEmpty())
     {
       on_actionSave_triggered();
     }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionundo_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->undo();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionRedo_triggered()
{
   ui->textEdit->redo();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionCoty_triggered()
{
   ui->textEdit->copy();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionPaste_triggered()
{
   ui->textEdit->paste();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionCut_triggered()
{
   ui->textEdit->cut();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionImages_Veiwer_triggered()
{

   QString OpenImages = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Choose image"), "" ,tr("Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)") );

   if(QString::compare(OpenImages, QString()) != 0)
     {
       QImage image;
       bool valid = image.load(OpenImages);

       if(valid)
         {
          Image =  new ImagesViewer(this);
          Image->

         }
     }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionPDF_Veiwer_triggered()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_actionAudio_Player_triggered()
{

}
```

файл mainwidow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "imagesviewer.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();

private slots:
  void on_actionAdd_triggered();

  void on_actionOpen_triggered();

  void on_actionSave_triggered();

  void on_actionSave_As_triggered();

  void on_actionundo_triggered();

  void on_actionRedo_triggered();

  void on_actionCoty_triggered();

  void on_actionPaste_triggered();

  void on_actionCut_triggered();

  void on_actionImages_Veiwer_triggered();

  void on_actionPDF_Veiwer_triggered();

  void on_actionAudio_Player_triggered();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  ImagesViewer *Image;

  QString mFileName;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

файл imagesviewer.cpp

```
#include "imagesviewer.h"
#include "ui_imagesviewer.h"

ImagesViewer::ImagesViewer(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::ImagesViewer)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

ImagesViewer::~ImagesViewer()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

файл imageviewer.h

```
#ifndef IMAGESVIEWER_H
#define IMAGESVIEWER_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
  class ImagesViewer;
}

class ImagesViewer : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit ImagesViewer(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~ImagesViewer();

private:
  Ui::ImagesViewer *ui;
};

#endif // IMAGESVIEWER_H
```

и вот скриншот файла .ui класса imagesviewer
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

извините за говнокод и тупой вопрос просто новичок

Comment: Почему он там должен быть?

Comment: всмысле почему?

Comment: Найдите [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) метод `label`. У меня не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Поле метки `label`, которое Вы поместили в окно, находится не в классе `ImageViewer`, а в классе `Ui::ImageViewer`, объект которого включен в Ваш класс через поле `ui`

Соответственно, обращение к этому полю будет выглядеть так:

```
this->ui->label...
```

`this`, разумеется, можно не писать.

***UPD***

Как подсказал @gil9red:

1. Имя переменной - это то имя элемента интерфейса, которое Вы видите в дизайнере.
2. Поле `ui` приватное и не доступно снаружи класса `ImageViewer`. Есть три пути решения данной проблемы:

2.1 Сделать поле публичным. (работать будет, но это, как по мне, неправильное решение)

2.2. Сделать в классе `ImageViewer` метод, который будет возвращать указатель на `ui`(это лучше)

2.3. Сделать в классе `ImageViewer` метод, который будет получать то, что  нужно поместить в `label` и выполнять всю работу с этим элементом. А из `MainWindow` Вы будете вызывать этот метод с необходимыми данными

Comment: Можно еще добавить, что переменная того label такое же как object name в дизайнере или это можно в `Ui::ImagesViewer` подглядеть. И чтобы из вне обратиться к `ui` нужно объявить поле в public `Ui::ImagesViewer *ui;`, тогда можно сделать так: `Image->ui->label...`, либо сделать метод, что в `ImagesViewer` вернет тот `label` из `ui`

Comment: не работает((( ладно спасибо всеравно

Comment: Вы где пытаетесь добраться до `label`? здесь: `       if(valid)
         {
          Image =  new ImagesViewer(this);
          Image->

         }`, Так там и не будет работать. Поле `ui` у Вас приватное и доступно только в классе `ImageViewer`, а Вы хотите до него добраться снаружи класса

Comment: @nursultan Посмотрите дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь метод для доступа к label

```
void ImagesViewer::setTextLabel(const QString& text)
{
    ui->label->setText(text);
}
```